# What does session_set_cookie_params($lifetime) do?

Tags: php

I am having a tough time understanding the concept of sessions in PHP . I have gone through the text that I am following 
and multiple tutorials online . So far my understanding of sessions are :

Sessions last till a browser is closed or a timeout set on the browser . When you start a session , PHP checks for an incoming session id (a cookie on the client) and then you can get/set session variables which are stored in a file on the server for that session id .

My confusion is with the function : session_set_cookie_params($lifetime) . Does this set the Session id  cookie on the client for $lifetime changing the default behavior of session ending on browser close ?

I tried something like :

```
<?php
$lifetime=strtotime('+1 year');
echo $lifetime;                                                 
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']='John';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The expiration date for the SessionId cookie doesnt seem to change and a new session id cookie is getting generated when I refresh the page.I was also seeing a video which says "unlike cookies sessions do not have an expiry time . They typically end when you close the browser".That seems to be fair as that is what sessions should be about . So my question is what does session_set_cookie_params($lifetime); actually do ? Can you make session cookie  persists?

Answer (score 1):

> session_set_cookie_params — Set the session cookie parameters

Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.

This function updates the runtime ini values of the corresponding PHP ini configuration keys which can be retrieved with the ini_get().

Reference:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php